# window.location.href is not working on Google Chrome in Asp.Net MVC application

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hello I have an issue with jquery `window.location.href` in my asp.net mvc application what I am  doing is I have a grid view with the help of `Html.actionlink` I am calling ajax request which deletes the row from database, 
after deleting record i have to **redirect or reload my page on same view** in ajax success:

My Webgrid

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("ID", "ID",canSort:false),
    grid.Column("Area", "Area",canSort:false),
    grid.Column("", header: "Actions", style: "grid-actions", format: @<text>
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", null, "", new { }, new { data_id = item.ID, @class = "Delete-Row" })
</text>)
    ))
```

And my JQuery Ajax

```
   $(".Delete-Row").on('click', function () {
var Id = $(this).data("id");
            var isTrue = confirm("Are you want To delete")
            if (isTrue) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("DeletaArea", "SetupHr")', 
                    data: { id: Id },
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function (data) {
                        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("IndexArea", "SetupHr")';
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("IndexArea", "SetupHr")';                       }
                });
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: hmm...Are you sure your ajax call worked?

Comment: Ajax is Working proper ,

Comment: Basically i dose not takes to my target location , by the 'Html.actionlink'  it creates a default some thing like href="hrms/"account/IndexArea/

Comment: Could u use window.location.reload(true); instead of @url.action ?

Comment: You are telling it to go to same href so it won't reload...use reload method as already mentioned. Better would be return data to update page with so you don't need reload at all

Comment: its Working fine with firefox , and cant work with google crome

Comment: Why on earth are you using ajax if your just going to reload the page (the whole point of using ajax is to stay on the same page and your just degrading performance - you would be better off just doing a normal submit and redirect). But there is no reason to reload the page anyway - just remove the current row from the DOM in the success callback

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why Razor would fail to generate the @Url.Action methods you have there as I think they look correct.

However, in your question you mention to reload the page would be just fine as well? That can be done with

```
location.reload();
```

so:

```
success: function (data) {
                    location.reload(); 
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    location.reload(); 
                }
            });
```

Comment: @ImranLuhur Sure you can, just did.

Comment: @ImranLuhur FF support documented at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload